# URL load in Safari but not loading in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am facing an strange issue. I have a URL when I try to load that url in UIWebView it doesn't load web view remain blank but when I try to load the same url in Safari it works great and display the page. Is there any restriction for UIWebView like it can't load any specific type of widgets if webpage contain.

Thank in advance

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
webView.delegate = self; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl"]; 
NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView loadRequest:req];
```

Comment: No, there isn't any restrictions on `UIWebView` for loading urls. There are should be some problem with your code. Provide us some code so that we could help you.

Comment: Can you provide code?

Comment: Have you implemented the `UIWebViewDelegate` method `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` to see what the error is?

Comment: UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    webView.delegate = self;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl"];
    NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView loadRequest:req];

Comment: I have also Implement webview delegate there is no error occur while load url. it goes in the webViewDidFinishLoad.

Comment: it will be much easier to help you knowing the url you are not able to load

Comment: Sorry I understand your point but I can't share URL. if you any idea why this may be happen so you can help me.

Comment: Yes, if I change the url it work great. also if I keep the same URL and open it in Safari it works.like this [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:myURL];

Answer (score 0):

Behaviour on Safari and the iOS simulator on your local machine will be the same. Both use the same proxy settings configured in System Preferences.

However - and here's the trick - each has their own distinct cookie store. To get the same behaviour you should first reset Safari and the Simulator.

This caught me out. My Safari URL worked because I had previously stored cookie values that enabled the server to fulfil my request. On the Simulator, no such cookies existed and therefore the server couldn't respond. On the surface it appeared as if the `UIWebView` just didn't work. However, that wasn't the case

**Bottom line:** ***reset both and try again.***